# Is there a volume chart for Omni assets?

Tags: raw-data, charts, omni, historical-trade-data

I am looking for trade / transaction volume charts for Omni assets like http://www.ripplecharts.com/ (seeking information of for example - how many MaidSafeCoins have been traded in the last week and for how much). Is such a resource available anywhere?